# Angular @syncfusion color picker production error

Tags: angular, production, syncfusion

I've integrated @syncfusion in my project and I have an issue on production.

In dev mode, everything works perfectly.
However, in the production build I get this error:

```
main-es2015.acf25ea6f580926d6d22.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined
at e.initCultureInfo (main-es2015.acf25ea6f580926d6d22.js:1)
at e.preRender (main-es2015.acf25ea6f580926d6d22.js:1)
at e.appendTo (main-es2015.acf25ea6f580926d6d22.js:1)
at e.createSlider (main-es2015.acf25ea6f580926d6d22.js:1)
at e.createPicker (main-es2015.acf25ea6f580926d6d22.js:1)
at e.createWidget (main-es2015.acf25ea6f580926d6d22.js:1)
at e.render (main-es2015.acf25ea6f580926d6d22.js:1)
at e.appendTo (main-es2015.acf25ea6f580926d6d22.js:1)
at e.ngAfterViewInit (main-es2015.acf25ea6f580926d6d22.js:1)
at ao (main-es2015.acf25ea6f580926d6d22.js:1)
```

The code(simplified) is this:

```
<input ejs-colorpicker
       [inline]="false"
       type="color"
       class="color-picker"/>
```

My package.json:
"@syncfusion/ej2-angular-inputs": "^18.2.54",

it seems that an internal variable (tooltip) is not properly initialized.

Did anyone stumbled upon this?
I really like the widget and would't want to switch to something else.

Thanks,
David

Comment: Did you pay for this ? or Do you use trail version?

Comment: I'm using the trial version.

Comment: You would expect to have at least a licencing error not this kind of stuff.

Comment: I think that is the case..Don't use trail versions to develop, if you don't buy. Use free npm for your case. Don't waste your time using trail versions.

Comment: it all went so smoothly :)
Roger that, good point; 

Thanks!
Back to the drawing board :D